# Using check-box in one column to disable check-box in another column

Tags: javascript

I have a table with two columns of check-boxes, Amend[] and Delete[].  On any row, by checking either one the other is disabled, preventing both being checked. This is my attempt:

```
var amend=document.getElementByName('Amend');
var del=document.getElementByName('Delete');
function Amend(){
for(x=0;x<amend.length;x++)
    {
    if(amend[x].checked)
        {
        del[x].disabled=disabled;
        }
    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You want radio buttons, not checkboxes:

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Option 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Option 2</label>
```

No JavaScript required. Hooray for free functionality!

Comment: Radio buttons are required elements, what if a user selects the wrong button?  I want the user to be able to change their mind.

Comment: @user2948954 In that case, a third, default "None" option is the best choice. Radio buttons are when you need to select 0 or 1 items. Checkboxes are for 0 or more.

Comment: The table has over 100 rows. Each amend check-box has `name="amend[]"`, yet when I alert(amend.length) I get 0.

Comment: That is after checking more than one chechbox.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.  The problem was `getElementByName('amend')`.  It should be         `getElementsByName('amend[]')`, I was referring to one variable called amend instead of an array of elements called amend[].